# MySQL update with concat not worked

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I should add a zero before a string

on first, i select my data to verify

```
mysql> SELECT cp, LENGTH(cp), CONCAT(0, `cp`) FROM communes WHERE LENGTH(cp) < 5
ORDER BY cp ASC LIMIT 4;
+------+------------+-----------------+
| cp   | LENGTH(cp) | CONCAT(0, `cp`) |
+------+------------+-----------------+
| 1000 |          4 | 01000           |
| 1000 |          4 | 01000           |
| 1000 |          4 | 01000           |
| 1090 |          4 | 01090           |
+------+------------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

and it work well.

on second, i try to update

```
mysql> UPDATE communes SET cp = CONCAT(0,`cp`) WHERE LENGTH(cp) < 5;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 3447  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I don't understand why it don't work

for info

```
mysql> describe communes;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cp         | int(6)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dept       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| code_insee | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

thank you a lot

Comment: cp column is int. u need to make that varchar/char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CP column is an integer and not a string, thus it will always be treated as such. If you want to have a format of 6 digits changed to be a CHAR(6).

Comment: In the first `SELECT`, `LENGTH(cp)` is selected, which is an integer 4 (I presume).  Why does this not work for the second `UPDATE` query?

Comment: yes, it work now

one question : why CONCAT work with SELECT and no UPDATE ?

Comment: @cyphos Select his answer as the accepted answer if it's what helped you.  However, I still feel your second query should have worked if your first one gave you those results.  I haven't tested though.

Comment: The length will implicit convert the integer to char to evaluate its size. On the other hand the update will convert a varchar string to its integer value because its type is integer. Try to do a select with the follwing clause `where 1 = '000001'` or `where 1 = '001.00'` or even `where 1.0 = '0001.00` they will all return true since they are all converted to the same value type

Comment: Thank saamorim and BLaZuRE

Answer (score 1):

With the query below:

```
UPDATE communes
SET cp = CONCAT( CAST( 0 as char), `cp`) 
WHERE LENGTH(cp) < 5;
```

You must convert `Number` to `char` `("CAST")`